# can't add xib file to target membership

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xib

I am trying to add a custom window as a .xib file to my existing OSX project. When I added the xib file, I make sure the target is checked in the "Add to targets"

However, when I view the property of the xib file, it shows that it's not part of the desired target group

[The target isn't checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAgZ0.png)

Then I experimentally add the xib files into "Copy Files" in the build phases. Now the xib file's property looks a bit different, the target is checked but grayed out.

[Checked but grayed out target group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8iE.png)

Now when I try to access the xib file, for example, using

```
bool suc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GiphyDialog" owner:nil topLevelObjects:nil];
```

It always returns false.

Or if I try to load the xib file using a window controller:

```
[[Windowcontroller alloc ]initWithWindowNibName:@"GiphyDialog"];
NSWindow* win = windowController.window;
```

Even though the File's owner and the window reference are correctly configured (tested in a brand new project successfully), I always failed to load the window with the message **"failed to load window nib file 'GiphyDialog'."**

How can I add the xib files correctly to the desired target? It's really strange that with a newly created project, I have no problem adding xib files to the target, but with this project, it simply doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: The Deployment Target of the XIB is set to 10.10. I do not know how this happened but it might cause the issue (see image "The target isn't checked")

Comment: @shallowThought thanks for the reply. How should I configure the deployment target instead? Other options are macOS 10.x and later, with x ranging from 6 to 12.1. I tried different options but didn't change the grayed out issue

Comment: My mistake. I thought it's about an iOS target.

Comment: Maybe try adding the extension to the filename in your init...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xibs must be added to Copy Bundle Resources, not Copy Files.

Answer (score 0):

So I manage to figure out the problem. In my XCode project there is no **Copy Bundle Resources** under the **Build Phases**. But I can add it by clicking the + button on the top-left corner of **Build Phases**. Adding the xib file to the **Copy Bundle Resources** then fix my issue.